# Restrict only 1 file to use sendmail

Tags: apache-2.2, email, debian, iptables, sendmail

I want to restrict access to sendmail process, to only 1 php file /var/www/mysite/contact.php

How can I do this? Maybe there is a trick with Iptables or sendmail configuration?

I want to secure sendmail on my Debian Server, to avoid spam/hacking.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Debian then your sendmail process is likely to be `exim4` or `postfix`.  These programs have significantly different configuration processes, both of which are simpler than the process for the original `sendmail` program.

Sendmail tends to be used by multiple system processes, so restricting local access to only one process may cause problems.  (Many system monitoring processes will use email to notify you of issues.)

You can restrict outgoing connections to port 25 to only your email process with `iptables`.  This will prevent any malicious processes from sending email directly.

You can to rate limit outgoing emails with either `iptables` or your sendmail program (exim4 has this capability, postfix may have it).

You can restrict the valid sending user-ids to prevent random senders.  You could require the apache user to authenticate before sending email.  This will make it more difficult from code injected to your site to send email.

If you do your `contact.php` correctly, you can (and should) limit the sending domain to your domain.  Don't allow use of random domains on outgoing email. Use a Reply-To address if you want to reply to a name provided to `contact.php`.

Make sure you do the rest of the setup for your mail server to prevent your server from being classified as Spam.